# Running R / RStudio on Windows 10

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, windows-10

I've been using R / RStudio for several months on Windows 7 & 8. Now I've received the upgrade invitation from Microsoft but at the same time, I've heard that there were serious compatibility issues between ancient versions of Windows and Windows 10.
I would need to know if it's possible to run R / RStudio on Windows 10 without major issues.

Comment: RStudio is indeed compatible with Windows 10, and a number of people are already using this configuration without issues. If you do run any issues, please report them on or support forum: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/topics/200022748-RStudio-IDE

Answer (score 2):

I have personally tried to run R and Rstudio with Windows with no problems (at the moment). Needless to say, I am on a split setup where my work machine is a windows 10 OS and my home is a Windows 7 OS. However, I find myself using my Windows 7 OS due to familiarity (with the GUI) and potential compatibility issues (that I might not be aware of at the moment). I guess this is a personal gimmick of mine, but as with all 'new' OS, expect to be disappointed.

Comment: I wanted to note that I am running on x64 versions of windows for both.

Comment: In my case, I've got a windows // 32 bit  version. Should I expect major differences in R behavior?

Comment: If memory serves, the difference in x32 and x64 is how much RAM you can use. I believe the cap for x32 OS are 4GB of ram. Meaning, you can't use more than 4GB. In your case, I would have to say no. There will be no change. However since it is 'that time of year' (RAM is rather cheap lately) I would recommend a hardware upgrade (perhaps 8GB of ram?) and switch to a x64 version of windows. But as for your switch to windows 10, there is no discernible difference R-wise. I just personally dislike using the new Windows 10 GUI when it comes to managing folders and files.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently running R/Rstudio on Windows 10 at home. Haven't hit any snags yet. I wouldn't rush to deploy in an Enterprise environment, but as far as I can tell it seems stable enough where R operation is concerned.

Plus, you get Cortana (which, judging by the name, sounds a bit frumpier than Siri, but it *is* Windows after all)

Answer (score 1):

I installed Win 10 on my laptop (i7, 16g Ram) last week and so far it is working OK with R studio.  My desk computer is nearly the same specs as my laptop, but I am keeping it with Win 8.1 for now.

Comment: Update, I have been using R / Rstudio (daily) with Win10 for two months now.  I haven't experienced any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running R and RStudio on Windows 10 (both Home and Pro editions) with no fuss at all yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had also been working with both R and Rstudio in windows 7 and 8. However, Rstudio stopped working after upgrading to windows 10. R is still working appropriately. So, you could expect problems or no problems after upgrading to windows 10. Try holding down the control key while starting R studio.

Comment: However, the solution to such problems can be found here https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488508-RStudio-Desktop-Will-Not-Start I was able to repair the issue after reading through the link.