# R studio crashing repeatedly on windows 10

Tags: r, rstudio

Sorry in advance if this is OT, wasn't quite sure but saw similar questions here so I figured I'd give it a shot.

I recently made the switch from RGui to RStudio. I used RGui for years on various versions of windows with no problems, including windows 10. However, when I switched over to RStudio I started getting repeated crashes/freezes. I've tried using it on other versions of windows and am not seeing any issues. The problem doesn't seem to be restricted to any particular function as I've had it happen during view(data), cor.test(x,y,...), T.aov(...), and a few others. All of which run without incident in RGui.

To restart RStudio when this happens I need to go in through the task manager, as the program becomes fully non-responsive. I've seen conflicting reports online that this may be a windows 10 compatibility issue, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789314/running-r-rstudio-on-windows-10).

1) Is this indeed an RStudio/windows 10 compatibility issue?
2) Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: You're probably better off in the RStudio support forums. Also, probably better to say you made the switch from RGui to RStudio. Presumably you are still using R...

Comment: I've had no problems like this on Win10 so far. Which RStudio version are you using?

Comment: The most recent version (0.99.903).

Comment: I've also had problems with windows 10 and rstudio crashing more often than with windows 7

Comment: Persist here as RStudio is light years ahead of RGui. Can you elaborate when you are getting the error? Is there a pattern using particular functions?

Comment: @boshek there doesn't seem to be any pattern. It has happened while using multiple functions from a variety of packages. I'm also noticing that RStudio somehow forgets where package dependencies are and tells me they don't exist, but if I go to cran I can download them manually so that's weird too. At first I thought it had to do with my large data overloading the memory, but even small matrices are doing it

Comment: I use RStudio on Windows 10 often and haven't encountered any problem. However program crash/freeze can be very complex, with reasons ranging from computer hardware (for example limited RAM), disk space to software (what version of R, what RProfile, startup options). If you can collect more information and error log, it may help you or someone here or from RStudio to identify the problem. Also see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488508-RStudio-Desktop-Will-Not-Start

Comment: @warmoverflow While you were typing it seems I addressed one comment regarding limited RAM. I've pretty much ruled that out. The rest though I will look in to. Not sure what you mean by RProfile and startup options. can you elaborate please?

Comment: RProfile http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html, also error log file location https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554756-RStudio-Application-Logs

Comment: @Jesse001 I am assuming you've tried re-installing?

Comment: @boshek several times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed some compatibility issues with the current RStudio release in this particular configuration:

1. R 3.3.x (or greater),
2. A 32bit version of R,
3. The current release of RStudio,
4. Windows.

The typical problems we've seen include crashes when attempting to generate `ggplot2` plots, or R errors emitted by `dplyr` becoming IDE crashes.

The underlying problem results from a change in the toolchain used to compile R 3.3.x -- the current release of RStudio does not have the necessary changes to accommodate this. Fortunately, there are a couple of solutions:

1. Try installing the [RStudio Preview Release](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/),
2. Try switching to a 64bit version of R,
3. Try rolling back to R 3.2.5.

Comment: I had a weird problem appear with rstan::traceplot(stanfit) crashing using 32-bit R. Switching to 64-bit R worked for me in this instance. This was with R version 3.5.0.

Comment: In my case, installing only a 32bit version instead of both helped.

Comment: Installing RStudio Preview Release did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to advise I had an issue with Windows 10 1803 and RStudio 1.1456 crashing too. Opened and closed immediately. Event viewer shows faulting module was **ISD_Tablet.dll**, this relates to **Wacom Tablet Service**.
Disabled this Wacom Tablet Service and RStudio now launches. Bugged me for ages, so thought I'd share!